# Provide better error messages to ANTLR v4 generated parsers?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Could someone provide pointers, how to optimize error messages from ANTLR generated parsers?

This message speaks to me, but probably not to the one, who should your the final tool:

```
    >> grun Php start -gui

    function f() { $d = 23; $f = 12; }

    line 1:24 missing '}' at '$f'
    line 1:33 extraneous input '}' expecting {<EOF>, 'interface', '(object)', 'yield', '`',
 'trait', 'namespace', '__TRAIT__', 'echo', '(unset)', 'abstract', '__FUNCTION__', '"', 'do',
 'use', 'throw', '@', 'print', 'global', 'inlcude_once', 'goto', 'empty', 'class', '!',
 'foreach', '__METHOD__', '-', 'while', '(double)', 'exit', 'if', 'require', '__NAMESPACE__',
 'isset', 'array', 'break', 'final', '__halt_compiler', '$', 'isempty', '+', '(array)',
 'switch', 'clone', 'declare', '(bool)', '~', '(string)', '[', 'continue', '__LINE__', '+++',
 'const', 'new', '__CLASS__', '__FILE__', 'unset', '(', 'try', '{', '\\', 'static', 'eval',
 'require_once', '(int)', 'for', 'list', 'return', ';', 'include', '__DIR__', T_VARIABLE,
 T_LNUMBER, T_DNUMBER, T_STRING_VARNAME, T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, StringLiteral,
 'function', '++', '--', T_START_HEREDOC, T_STRING}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement an ANTLRErrorStrategy. Book has lots of examples.  Chap 9. p149.
Ter

Comment: Is ANTLR v4.1 stable? Or should I use v4.0?

Comment: 4.1 is stable so go for it